# fread() problem in c while reading floating point numbers from a file

Tags: c, fwrite, fread, data-corruption

> Libraries used

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<time.h>
```

> Creating a dataset with random floating-points and printing on a newly created file

```
void createdataset(int Datasetsize,char * filename)
{
  FILE *f;
  int su;
  float v[Datasetsize];    

  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

  for(int i = 1; i<=Datasetsize;i++) 
    *(v+i)=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * 100;

  f=fopen(filename,"wb");
  su=fwrite(v ,sizeof(float) , Datasetsize , f);
  printf("%d\n",su);
  fclose(f);
}
```

> Reading the newly created file using fread() and displaying the number of successful attempts. It always gives unsuccessful attempts like it reads 120 records from 1000 and the rest are corrupted. I need to resolve this issue.

```
void loadDataset (int DataSetSize, char *filename, float *v) 
{
  FILE *fp;
  int s;

  fp = fopen( filename , "r" );
  if( fp==NULL) 
    printf("File cant be opened");

  s=fread(v , sizeof(float), DataSetSize, fp );
  printf("%d\n",s);
  for( int i=0; i<DataSetSize; i++)
  {
    printf("\t%f",*(v+i));
  }

  fclose(fp);
}
```

> Main function

```
void main()  
{ 
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    int datasetsize;
    char filein[50];
    char *fi=filein, ds; 

    printf("Enter the size of the datasetsize: ");
    scanf("%d",&datasetsize);

    float v[datasetsize];

    printf("%d\n",datasetsize);
    printf("Enter input file name: ");
    scanf("%s",filein);
    printf("%s\n",filein);
    createdataset(datasetsize,fi);
    loadDataset(datasetsize, fi, v);
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i<=Datasetsize;i++)` = undefined behavior. Arrays in C start at 0. Also you're never checking for any error codes.

Comment: Please format your code. It is badly readable now.

Comment: @chost error code of what ?

Comment: you write binary, if you are under Windows open file with "wb" and "rb"

Comment: @chost `fopen` can fail due to bad permissions, use: `if (fopen(...) == NULL) { /* error */ }` same for `fread`: `if((s=fread(v , sizeof(float), DataSetSize, fp )) != sizeof(float)) { /* error */ }`, `scanf` also returns the number of succesfully filled fields or `EOF`, check its result: `if (scanf("%d",&datasetsize) != 1) { /* check */ }`, as you can see, C is not a protective language :(

Comment: You should __not__ change your post with improvements from others. It will make your question cannot be understood.

Comment: did you at least recompile and test again after correcting the `for` thanks to @John3136 ?

Comment: @John3136 I have made the changes but still same error. What could be the error codes as the data is being retrieved but with other values like  1378407397002315800000000000000.000000  -1.#QNAN0

Comment: @chost how mush value *su* you print in *createdataset* and *s* you print in *loadDataset* ? What value you read for *datasetsize* ?

Comment: As @bruno said have you changed `fp = fopen( filename , "r" );` to `fp = fopen( filename , "rb" );` ?

Comment: @bruno good catch, for sure OP is on Windows (`conio.h`)

Comment: @Frankie_C yeah i've changed fp = fopen( filename , "r" ); to fp = fopen( filename , "rb" ); but still the same

Comment: @DavidRanieri He is on windows per sure also because he already used `"wb"` opening the file for writing.

Comment: @chost also "wb" rather than "w" if you are under windows

Comment: @bruno Thanks man you saved my day. It is working fine now.

Comment: @chost ok, I put that in an answer to be more visible, remarks have a temporary live

Answer (score 1):

Including *conio.h* you are under Windows

doing

> ```
> su=fwrite(v ,sizeof(float) , Datasetsize , f);
> ...
> s=fread(v , sizeof(float), DataSetSize, fp );
> ```

you write and read binary, under windows to write and read binary file you need to use "wb" and "rb" so you need to replace

> ```
> f=fopen(filename,"w");
> ...
> fp = fopen( filename , "r" );
> ```

by

> ```
> f=fopen(filename,"wb");
> ...
> fp = fopen( filename , "rb" );
> ```

but  see also remarks below

---

out of that :

In *createdataset* :

you do not check you was able to open the file, you need to check *fp* is not *NULL*, for instance using `perror` to indicate the reason :

```
if (fp == NULL)
{
  perror("cannot open file to write"); 
  exit(-1);
}
```

Also to do

> ```
> *(v+i)=...
> ```

is not very readable to set the array elements, just do

```
v[i] = ...
```

In *loadDataset* you cannot do

> ```
> if( fp==NULL) 
> printf("File cant be opened");
> ```

and continue like there is no error, you need to stop the execution of the function doing a `return` or putting the rest in an `else` branch, and again you can use `perror` to indicate the problem :

```
if (fp == NULL)
{
   perror("cannot open the file to read");
   exit(-1);
}
```

Also to do

> ```
> printf("\t%f",*(v+i));
> ```

is not very readable to access the array element, just do

```
printf("\t%f", v[i]);
```

In *main* :

> ```
> scanf("%d",&datasetsize);
> ```

if the user does not input a valid int the behavior is undefined after because *datasetsize* is not set, better to do for instance :

```
if ((scanf("%d",&datasetsize) != 1) || (datasetsize < 1)) {
  puts("invalid size);
  return -1;
}
```

Also

> ```
> char filein[50];
> ...
> scanf("%s",filein);
> ```

has an undefined behavior if the user input more than 49 characters, do

```
 scanf("%49s",filein);
```

even it is also better to check `scanf`returns 1 in case the *stdin* is redirected in an empty input file

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bruno points out the basic problems.
As a demo I post the working code here because was not possible in comments:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
void createdataset(int Datasetsize, char *filename, float *v)
{
    FILE *f;
    int su;

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f)
    {
        printf("Error creating file. Program aborted...\n");
        abort();
    }

    printf("Writing %d entries to file \"%s\".\n", Datasetsize, filename);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 1; i <= Datasetsize; i++)
    {
        *(v + i) = ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * 100;
        printf("\t%f\n",*(v+i));
    }
    su = fwrite(v, sizeof(float), Datasetsize, f);
    printf("Wrote %d floats to file\n", su);
    fclose(f);
}

void loadDataset(int DataSetSize, char *filename, float *v)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int s;
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cant be opened");
        return;
    }

    s = fread(v, sizeof(float), DataSetSize, fp);
    printf("Read data set composed of %d entries.\n", s);
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSetSize; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%f\n", *(v + i));
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    int datasetsize;
    char filein[50];
    char *fi = filein, ds;

    printf("Enter the size of the datasetsize: ");
    scanf("%d", &datasetsize);
    printf("%d\n", datasetsize);

    float v_out[datasetsize];
    float v_in[datasetsize];

    printf("Enter input file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filein);
    printf("%s\n", filein);

    createdataset(datasetsize, fi, v_out);
    loadDataset(datasetsize, fi, v_in);

    int errors=0;
    for (int i=0; i<datasetsize; i++)
        if (v_in[i] != v_out[i])
        {
            printf("Error in/out in position %d, v_in=%f, v_out=%f\n", i, v_in[i], v_out[i]);
            errors++;
        }

    printf("Completed with %d error(s).\n", errors);
}
```

I fixed prints for a more readable apparence and added a check for errors (even if not fully correct comparing floats).